# Dont know why am getting Haskell "<interactive>:48:1: parse error on input ‘./’" using WinGHCi 1.0.6 and

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie in Haskell running  Below  Haskell  code  Chapter 4   of RealWorld  Haskell Book and getting

```
 <interactive>:48:1: parse error on input ‘./’
```

**This  is  what  i  executed  on  WinGHCi 1.0.6**

```
Prelude> :load Interact    
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Interact.hs, interpreted )    
Ok, modules loaded: Main.    
*Main> --make Interact    
*Main> :load Interact    
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Interact.hs, interpreted )    
Ok, modules loaded: Main.    
*Main> ./Interact "infrank.txt" "outfrank.txt"    
    *<interactive>:48:1: parse error on input ‘./’*
```

Can  Anyone  please  help? as i  tried  to  google  around with no hope

**Below is  the  code  from RealWorld Haskell Chapter 4**

```
-- file: ch04/Interact.hs    
-- Save this in a source file, e.g. Interact.hs

import System.Environment (getArgs)
interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do

  input <- readFile inputFile    
  writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do

          args <- getArgs
          case args of
            [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
            _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

        -- replace "id" with the name of our function below
        myFunction = id
```

Comment: `ghci` interprets Haskell expressions. `./Interact` doesn't look like one, it looks like an executable file name. To run an executable file, use a shell. In `ghci`, try typing a Haskell expression, like `main`. Or, if you want to pass arguments to `main`, try `:main infrank.txt outfrank.txt`.

Comment: Thank   you @n.m...it   Worked  like  a charm when using :main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just looked on the [chapter 4](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html) and you seem to be confused between ghci prompt and shell (cmd.exe in case of Windows).

You have to run this command in shell (For Unix systems) or `cmd.exe` in Windows:

```sh
ghc --make Interact.hs
./Interact "infrank.txt" "outfrank.txt"
```

Also the book seems to have some error with it as they are producing an executable named `InteractWith` using `ghc --make InteractWith` and then using `Interact` instead of `InteractWith`.

Comment: Thank  you   Sibi...........i did  change InteractWith   to  Interact  myself.I think  like you pointed out  i was using wrong command in window.It worked  fine  when  i  did  use  a proper  command.Again  thank you very much